# Указание адреса WebSocket сервера на Node.js

Tags: node.js, сервер, websocket

Добрый день, довольно давно использую код для создания WS-соединения на стороне сервера из этого примера:
https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/node-websockets#functionality

Для локалхоста все хорошо, но на реальном сервере мне бы хотелось создать несколько ws-серверов на разных адресах, в зависимости от директории файла, то есть:

`node /index.js` >> ws://site.com:5000

`node /folder/index.js` >> ws://site.com/folder:5000

`node /folder2/index.js` >> ws://site.com/folder2:5000

Я не знаю точно откуда получить директорию и как ее добавить в адрес, надеюсь на вашу помощь :)

Answer (score 1):

Используйте `process.argv[1]` для получения первого аргумента, переданного в командной строке node. А дальше из этой строки извлеките директорию и делайте, что вам нужно